# Como asociar cualquier evento de javascript(onmousemove,onclick etc..) usando objetos de tipo prototipo

Tags: javascript

Buenas gente ver si me podeis  ayudar tengo una "clase" llamada barra que tu la pasas por encima de una caja se crea pero no se mueve y me gustaria saber porque

```
caja=document.getElementById("caja");
        caja.style.width = "800px";
        caja.style.height = "600px";
        caja.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";

        pelota = new Pelota();
        pelota.crearBola();
        //clearInterval(pelota.intervalo);
        raqueta = new Barra();
        raqueta.crearBarra();
        caja.onmousemove=function (elEvento){
            eventoBarra = window.event||elEvento;
            cx = eventoBarra.clientX;
            cy = eventoBarra.clientY;
            console.log("Cliente X "+cx+" Cliente Y "+cy);
            if (cx >= 0 && cx <= parseInt(caja.style.width) - parseInt(raqueta.width)){
                raqueta.left= cx;
                console.log("Valor del ancho de la barra: "+raqueta.left);
                //contLeftBarra = cx;
                //informacionDelJuego();
            }
        } 

function Barra(){
this.width=100;
this.height=20;
this.left=380;
this.top=520;
```

} 
Barra.prototype.crearBarra=function(elEvento){
    this.barra=document.createElement("div");//creamos la barra en el entorno de juego
    this.barra.style.height = this.height+"px";
    this.barra.style.width = this.width+"px";
    this.barra.style.backgroundColor = "#9a0827";
    this.barra.style.position = "absolute";
    this.barra.style.left = this.left+"px" ;
    this.barra.style.top = this.top+"px";
    this.barra.style.borderRadius = "1em";
    caja.appendChild(this.barra);

}

Comment: Semejante cantidad de codigo no ayuda a detectar tu error. Podrias ser mucho mas claro sobre donde esta el problema? mira [ask]

Comment: he creado una caja que es de fondo negro dentro de esta caja hay dos elementos una pelota y una barra la pelota esta en constante movimiento y la barra deberia de moverse cada vez que que pasas el raton por encima de la caja se mueve conociendo el cliente x del raton pero por alguna razon no se me mueve la barra